# How are people using Yeoman?

Tags: backbone.js, ember.js, yeoman

I've been playing around with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and it's pretty great.
I'm wondering how people are integrating the resulting frontend app with backends?

Are you keeping them as separate code bases that potentially run on separate servers?
Are you stuffing the whole directory in a rails public folder and pointing the root route at index.html buried in there?

Up until now I've only ever used helpful gems to integrate backbone or ember into the rails asset pipeline. I could certainly move various files into the assets directory of a rails app but that kinda defeats the purpose of Yeoman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far I only used it to make and maintain the frontend app, using ajax to get all the information needed from the backend deployed as another project (web service).